# Unit test validation with chai

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, chai

I am new to unit testing with chai, and I want to write one for this simple code that compares 2 items. my code:::

This is a sample test followed by the main code

```
describe('Challenge', function() {
  it('should return the right array', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(number_game(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
    assert.deepEqual(number_game(0,0), []);
  });
});

function number_game(x, y) {
    var arr = [];
    if (x > y) {
        //if x is greater than y
        //print out even numbers between x and y
        for (let i = x; i > y; i--) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {

                arr.push(i);
            }
        }
        return arr
    } else if (x < y) {
        for (let i = x; i < y; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {

                arr.push(i);
            }
        }
        return arr
    } else {
        return ([]);
    }
    //nothing is done when x is equal to y

    return arr;
}
number_game(2, 12);
number_game(0, 0);
```

Comment: Is my test valid? if no, how do I write a valid test for this code

Comment: It looks good, but you're missing at least one thing: A test case that tests the behavior when `x > y`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's right. If you desire to make in a different form, you can use 'expect' in your test suite.

```
const expect = chai.expect;
expect(number_game(2,12)).to.eql([3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
expect(number_game(2,12)).to.be.an('Array');
```